# How to use javascript foreach loops to get return four?

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is an array and I want to use foreach loop to get the biggest number

Here is an array

```
 const array2 = ['a', 3, 4, 2]
```

What i try in JS:

```
 function biggestNumberInArray3(arr) {
  var largest = arr[0] || null;
  var number = null;
  arr.forEach (value => {
    number = value
    largest = Math.max(largest, number);
   })
  return largest;
  }
```

Looks like Math.max isn't work in here.

It returns NaN

Are there any other ways to use foreach loop to compare the elements in an array?

P.S.: this foreach loop will return 4

Comment: `forEach` don't return any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use forEach , you can just add a check for numbers in your code

```js
    function biggestNumberInArray3(arr) {
      var largest = null;
      var number = null;
      arr.forEach (value => {
     if(typeof(value) === "number"){
     number = value
        largest = Math.max(largest, number);
       }
      })
      return largest;
      }
      
      console.log(biggestNumberInArray3(['a', 3, 4, 2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to find the max number and `filter` it before the max operation as the presence of `a` will cause the result to be a `NaN`.

```js
const array2 = ['a', 3, 4, 2]
var max = array2.filter((num)=> !isNaN(num)).reduce((a, b)=>{
    return Math.max(a, b);
});
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 1):

***forEach don't return any value.***

You can use **[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and [**Math.max**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

1. use filter to remove all non-number values.
2. use Math.max to get highest value.

```js
 const array2 = ['a', 3, 4, 2]
 
 console.log(Math.max(...array2.filter(e=> !isNaN(e))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const array2 = ['a', 3, 4, 2]
var max = Math.max(...array2.filter(num => Number.isInteger(num)));
console.log(max);
```

Comment: Answers without proper explanation won't be helpful for future readers

Answer (score 0):

Remove the string from array, see demo. Not interested in efficient and simple code? `forEach()` only returns `undefined` so you'll need to get a side-effect in order to get any result. In the demo below there's a variable outside the loop that changes as the loop progresses. Eventually this variable will be the greatest number in the array.

---

### Demo

```js
/*
Math.max.apply()
======================================*/

const array = ['a', 3, 4, 2];

//Get rid of the string
const num = array.shift();

console.log(`Math.max.apply({}, arr) ========= ${Math.max.apply({}, array)}`);

/* 
forEach() 
=======================================*/

let max = 0;

array.forEach(num => {
  max = num > max ? max = num : max;
});

console.log(`array.forEach()  ================ ${max}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another solution using only `reduce()`:

```js
const array2 = ['a', 3, 4, 2, "hello", {hello:"world"}];

let res = array2.reduce((max, e) => isNaN(e) ? max : Math.max(max, e), null);

console.log(res);
```